# How to use join with two table and a parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have Table 1 with these 4 columns

```
FirstName LastName State ID
```

Table 2 with these 2 columns

```
ID Phone
```

How to join them with a parameter like this

```
SELECT Table1.FirstName, Table1.LastName FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
```

Doing this is giving me nothing. Please help

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a problem with what you entered. Are you setting @FirstName? Is there data in your database to support that call?

Comment: Problem seems to be with @FirstName...or may be their is no matching values for ID columns in table1 and table2

Comment: @samanime... FirstName gets the value from a parameter... and a simple query like select * from table 1 where FirstName  = atFirstName works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND FirstName = @FirstName
```

Comment: wow... thanks a ton patrick choi... this is exactly what I was looking for